# Calling original method with Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have a ProductRepository with 2 methods, GetAllProducts and GetProductByType, and I want to test the logic at GetProductByType. Internally, GetProductByType makes a call to GetAllProducts and then filters the correct ones.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    //returns all products in memory, db etc
}

public virtual IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByType(string type)
{
    return (from p in GetAllProducts() where p.Type == type select p).ToList();
}
```

So in my test I'd like to mock the call to GetAllProducts, so it returns a list of products defined at my test, and then call the original GetProductsByType, which will consume the mocked GetAllProducts.

I'm trying something like the code below but the original GetProductByType is not executed, it is mocked-out as well. In TypeMock I have a CallOriginal method that fixes this, but I can't figure it out with Moq. Any ideas?

```
var mock = new Mock<ProductRepository>();
mock.Setup(r => r.GetAllProducts()).Returns(new List<Product>() {p1, p2, p3});
var result = mock.Object.GetProductsByType("Type1");
Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Count());
```

Comment: I would just subclass your ProductRepository yourself and not Mock it at all. Your "FakeProductRepository" would return a hard coded list of products and you can test GetProductsByType against that list.

Comment: Great suggestion, haven't thought of that...Fridays!

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Set CallBase to true on your mock.  This will call the original virtual methods or properties if they exist, and haven't been set up to return a canned value.

```
var mock = new Mock<ProductRepository>() { CallBase = true };
```

Comment: My project is .Net Framework 4.8 And I registered mock.object to DI. And it does not works for me. But this solution is worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72639955/3558141

Answer (score 12):

today I found, in moq now can use this method:

```
 mockObj.Setup(obj => obj.FunctionA()).CallBase();
```